# Setting the Value of a Field With a Subclass of the Field's type

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, casting, bukkit

I have been working on this problem for more than 12 hours without success so if anyone can help with this or provide a different solution I will be eternally grateful. The main problem iv'e been running into is changing fields with the class inheritance structure which i will attempt to explain:

The "craftPlayer" variable is an instance of CraftPlayer which is a child class of CraftEntity. The CraftEntity class contains a Entity object which has the variable "uniqueID". So Basically all i'm trying to do is change that uniqueID variable for "craftPlayer". I don't have access to any of the classes so i'm using reflection. The problem i'm running into currently is trying to change the Entity variable which is inside "craftPlayer" the but i can't figure out a way to get the instance of that class as the "entity" variable is really an instance of EntityPlayer and not Entity

I realize this was very poorly explained so ask as many clarifying questions as you want. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
        CraftEntity craftPlayer = (CraftEntity) player;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<CraftEntity> craftEntityClass = getCraftEntityClass((Class<CraftEntity>) craftPlayer.getClass());

        for (Field field : craftEntityClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.getName().equals("entity")) {
                Object object = field.get(craftPlayer);
                EntityPlayer entity = (EntityPlayer) object;
                entity.uniqueID = new UUID(0L, 0L);
                field.set(entity, entity); //"entity" is really an instance of EntityPlayer which is a subclass of Entity so i am unable to change the field because upclassing does not seem to work
                break;
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

Here is the CraftEntity class to better show what im doing

```
public abstract class CraftEntity implements org.bukkit.entity.Entity {   
    protected final CraftServer server;
    protected net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.Entity entity;
    private EntityDamageEvent lastDamageEvent;
}
```

Comment: please post `CraftEntity` class declaration

Comment: *"unable to change"* What do you mean? Does an exception throw? If so, what does it say?

Comment: @Radiodef I will get an IllegalArgumentException saying: Can not set Entity field to EntityPlayer, because "entity" is only a sub class of Entity, it is really an EntityPlayer

Comment: What are you trying to do with `field.set(entity, entity);`? Did you mean `field.set(craftPlayer, entity);`? Note that if all you do is change a field of `entity`, you do not need to call `set`, because you have a reference to the entity inside `craftPlayer`.

Comment: Also, I feel like it's necessary to say that if you are the one that wrote `CraftEntity` class, using reflection is a completely wrong way to approach this. Just make `entity` public or make a setter/getter.

Comment: @Radiodef Oh my god. You're right, i don't need to set the field to the new value! I feel like an idiot now lol. The reason why I didn't think it was working is because this code was getting called before the players saved data was actually loaded so once that happened any changes I made disappeared!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`entity.uniqueID = new UUID(0L, 0L);` is enough to change the variable.
Trying to set the field to the new variable would have been redundant.

The problem was actually timing, this code was getting called before the player's saved data was loaded so once it was the changes I made were overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here?

```java
field.set(entity, entity);
```

If you wanted to change the field in the "craftPlayer" object shouldn't you be doing this?

```java
field.set(craftPlayer, entity);
```

Comment: That doesn't work because craftPlayer is not a CraftEntity object. It is a CraftPlayer object, which is a subclass of CraftEntity but regardless field.set() needs the exact type so it wouldn't work. I figured out problem though. Using field.set() would  have been completely redundant, just setting the entity.uniqueID variable was enough.